# Salesforce standard URLs are not being supported by Iframes..... :(

Tags: visualforce, iframe

```
<apex:page >
   <apex:iframe src="https://na12.salesforce.com/01ZU0000000NHAt" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
</apex:page>
```

This was working example but now it's not working.

After my some of trail and errors, I noticed that standard salesforce URLs are not supported when they used in an Iframe. You can consider the above vf page as an example.

The other thing, I noticed is that the below Iframe works and runs successfully

```
<apex:page >
     <apex:iframe src="/apex/MyVFPage" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
</apex:page>
```

After this trial, I googled and realised that this started to happen since spring'15 release.

**Do anyone have any hacks on how can I display a Dashboard on either a vf page or on a home page component?**

Also, let's all vote in here for salesforce to consider it...if no one found any hack...

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XttAAE

Thanks in advance..